# URL redirect from a button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, document-library

I have added a button into my SharePoint list using SharePoint designer.

I want to be able to open a document from the button. So I go the url for the word document by going properties on the normal link in a SharePoint list for a document.

I then put the link in a hidden column. I am now trying to use `window.location.href = {column name}` and I am keep getting below error.

> 500 error.

I want to use a button to open a document because I want to trigger a workflow off when the user clicks on OPEN DOCUMENT button.

Does anyone have any ideas whats the best way ?

Comment: When you hover on the button, what URL you see at the bottom of the browser? And check whether its correct?

Comment: A calculated column with HTML would work for this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the URL in a column in the list, then you'll have to either:

- Display it in the form and retrieve its value from the DOM to use in
  your script, or
- Use SOAP/REST to retrieve the column value from the
  list

What you're trying to do above would be a little magical. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hover on the button you can see left bottom side which URL you are going to re-directing so check with the URL, else Go to that column which include URL test it manually whether URL is correct.

Comment: when I hover over the button, there is not an url on the bottom left hand side .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calculated column. The output type should be set to `Number`. Something like:

```
=CONCATENATE("<div><a href='http://mysite/list/ListName/DisplayForm.aspx?ID=",[ID],"'>Click Here</a></div>")
```

Another option would be to setup a multi-line text field, with rich text. Then run a workflow each time a new item is added to populate that text field with the HTML you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a data view for this.  Use your button in said data view and onclick of each item run some JavaScript.  Your script would trigger the workflow then open your document.

I like the data view here because it is easy to embed something like an ID or any other property into your button, div, etc.  I know you can get the same effect using a calculated column, but in my experience that can be clunky and doesn't always work how I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with JSLink. Refer: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a